# Changing pulseaudio default per-user output device

Tags: configuration, non-root-user, pulseaudio

Is there a way to change or set the default per-user pulseaudio output device without having write access to the system configuration (but of course having write access to the user configuration in $HOME/.config/pulse)?

There already is an answer how to solve this iff one had write access to the system, however, in this scenario, one doesn't always have, and the user choices also are different, so a system-wide default won't always work either.

Thanks for any good answer